# How to format the output

Tags: shell

```
 bid     bookname        author
 1       unix    sumitaba das
 2       java    balaguruswamy
 3       db      elmasari
 4       c       padma redddy
 5       ada     yeshwant kanetkar
 6       datastructure   padma redddy
 7       microprocessor  padma redddy
```

How do i format the above output for proper spaces between the columns so that it will look as follows:

```
bid     bookname        author
1       unix            sumitaba das
2       java            balaguruswamy
3       db              elmasari
4       c               padma redddy
5       ada             yeshwant kanetkar
6       datastructure   padma redddy
7       microprocessor  padma redddy
```

I am capturing the result of an SQL query into a file and displaying the file in my program.

Comment: Please fix your formatting so we can see what you're trying.

Comment: i am finding it difficult to edit just joined today.what i want is third column values to start exactly from where author does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "_" temporary in names

```
awk 'NF==4{$3=$3 "_" $4; $4=""} 1' foo.txt | column  -t  | tr '_' ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your input has its columns separated by tabs and you've pasted what it looks like with tabstop set to 8. If that's the case then you can take advantage of the tabs to imrpove on slitvinov's answer:

```
your_sql_command | column -s '<TAB>' -t
```

You must enter a literal tab in the command line where I have written . To do that at the shell command line, press Ctrl-V and then Tab. If you're putting it into a shell script, just make sure your text editor inserts an actual tab instead of converting it to a series of spaces. Or depending on your shell, this might work:

```
your_sql_command | column -s $'\t' -t
```

Comment: So stick a pipe in there and run that nifty column command (`./mysql -h localhost -uroot -p"root" < execute | column -s $'\t' -t > result`) or do `column -s $'\t' -t < result` afterward. (This was a response to a comment that has been deleted.)

Comment: Alan:hey i tried the column thing but cygwin doesnt support column

Comment: Cygwin... bummer. There is a similar command called `expand`, which does almost the same thing but you have to specify the column width. Instead of `column -s $'\t' -t` you'd use `expand -t 10,40` and adjust the numbers until it looks good. The trouble is later when a longer bookname gets added to the databse, you might have to adjust those numbers again.